# What's the selector to color word values in CSS files in TextMate?

Tags: css, themes, textmate

My present TextMate theme (Ruby Blue) is nice, except there's one annoying attribute that I haven't been able to fix.

When editing CSS, it doesn't apply any color to "word values" for properties.

See screenshot below -- for `width: 90%`, the 90% is highlighted.  However, for `display: block`, 'block' gets no highlighting.

[image]

What's the TextMate selector to allow me to color this?  I tried experimenting with different options in the theme editor and haven't been able to find it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `support.constant.property-value.css`.

(Hint: If you put your cursor in a word and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, a tooltip will popup and tell you the current selector for the cursor position, as well as any parent selectors.)

Comment: Nitpick: it's ⌃⇧P (control+shift+p), not ⇧⌥P, which introduces a product sign, `∏`.  (Unless I've changed my settings, but I don't think I did..)

Comment: Meant control, typed option. Thanks.